# Does the npm cache speed up `npm install`?

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

Consider the following builds:

- [3rd build without npm cache](https://github.com/ugultopu/setup-node-without-cache/runs/4597615459?check_suite_focus=true)
- [3rd build with npm cache](https://github.com/ugultopu/setup-node-with-cache/runs/4597616727?check_suite_focus=true)

These two repositories are almost identical, with the only difference being the latter repository caches `npm` via the `setup-node` GitHub Action, whereas the former one does not. In other words, the only difference between the repositories is at the `.github/workflows/main` file:

```yaml
name: Build Pipeline
on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '11'
          # Following line is present only on the latter repository
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
```

Although the build at "setup-node-with-cache" successfully uses npm cache (as evident by the output of the `Run actions/setup-node@v2` step), run time of `Run npm install` step is almost the same as the corresponding step of the build at "setup-node-without-cache".

Isn’t the run time of `Run npm install` step of the build at "setup-node-with-cache" supposed to be significantly shorter than the corresponding step of the build at "setup-node-without-cache", since it is supposed to use the cached npm packages? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It really does not seem to be, at least on GitHub Actions. The workaround that I found is caching the actual `node_modules` folder, even though it is "not recommended". Caching the actual `node_modules` folder does speed up `npm install`.